# How to save the contents of a webpage that is constantly updating

Tags: php, linux

I am trying to be able to save the contents of a file that is always getting new information added to it to a file.
The webpage clears and starts listing again when you refresh it.
So id need to load the webpage for a couple of minutes to collect a couple of lines of data then save it to a file. How can I do this? I will be running the file that I make as a cron to run every hour. The webpage that is constantly updating is [here](http://panel.joshdouch.co:10001/).

Thanks